# How to autosize width to parents width size based on numbers of child's div

Tags: css

I would like to auto size the child divs to the width size of the parent. this has to be autosize as I would like to add new or remove the child divs on the fly. I tried width:auto but that doesnt do it. is there something im missing?

I need all the child divs to add up to the parent's width size. so if the parents width size is 100px. and i have two child divs inside i would like the childs width size to be 50px. and so on. if its 3 then the size should change to 33.33px.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.box {
  padding: 50px;
  width: auto;
}

.clearfix{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="box" style="background-color:#bbb"> <-- needs to be auto size in case more are added or removed -->
  <p>Some text inside the box.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="background-color:#ccc">
  <p>Some text inside the box.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you asking

Comment: Sorry, i have update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex` will help you with this

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Some text
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Some text inside the box.
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Some text inside the box. Some text inside the box. Some text inside the box. Some text inside the box.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. not sure whats the difference than my code above. I do have display: flex, on the above.

Comment: I've made a small change as you would've had issues with varying amounts of text in each box.